# Ample divisors on $T$-varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, localization, positivity, equivariant, ample-bundles

***Question:*** how does one use a torus action to help decide whether a divisor or line bundle is ample?

***In more detail:*** I have a (normal, but usually rather singular) $T$-variety $X$, where $T$ is an algebraic torus (e.g. $T = (\mathbb{C}^*)^n$). Also, $X$ admits a $T$-equivariant closed embedding into $\mathbb{P}(V)$, where $V$ is a multiplicity free $T$-module. In particular, $T$ has finitely many fixed points on $X$. (They actually coincide with the $T$-fixed points on $\mathbb{P}(V)$, but this is probably irrelevant.)

I have good control on the $T$-invariant curves on $X$. (Usually, there are infinitely many, however they occur in well-understood small-dimensional families.)

I would like to understand the ample cone of $X$. In particular, given a $T$-invariant divisor, I would like to be able to decide in a combinatorial fashion whether it is ample or not. For example, one could imagine something like: a $T$-invariant divisor $D$ on $X$ is ample if it meets every $T$-invariant curve. (This is probably too optimistic though...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Surely something akin to this setting is discussed in the literature?

Comment: Just to clarify, $T$ is a torus and it is not assumed it has a dense orbit in $X$, right?

Comment: Woops! yes T is an algebraic torus, and it doesn't have a dense orbit. (Usually its dimension will be much smaller than $X$.)

Comment: I edited to clarify.

Comment: Since your variety is projective, you can use Kleiman’s criterion for ampleness.  By properness of the Hilbert scheme (or more elementary alternatives) it suffices to use $T$-invariant (hence rational) curves.  Finally, using equivariant localization, it suffices to compute weights of your divisor class at the two $T$-fixed points of the normalization of your $T$-invariant curve.  For an example of such equivariant localization computations, you might consult de Jong - He - Starr.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you! Yes I had understood that I can use Kleiman and reduce to rational curves, but I don't know how to do the last step. Is the rough idea I pull the line bundle back to the normalization and check that it is positive, via localization? Re [dJHS]: do you mean the proof of Theorem 13.1?

Comment: "Is the rough idea ..."  Yes, that is precisely the idea.  The degree of the line bundle on the rational curve is the difference of the degree of the weights of the corresponding $1$-dimensional $T$-representation at the two fixed points.  (Of course that leads to a problem: which of the two differences is it? This can usually be "calibrated" by comparing with a known degree of a $T$-invariant curve.)

Comment: thanks Jason, this is very helpful. (For readers that have made it this far, I think Jason means that we should replace T by a generic C^* in T to make sense of degree  = weight at one end of P1 - weight at other end.)